# Combining an array based off value

Tags: php, arrays

Alright, I have been pulling my hair out on this one! I have tried an SQL call to add the features to a product, but since the product is one row and the features are not it creates a new row for each product. I thought I could add both to an array and join them based off the product ID. Here are the arrays

```
array
  0 => 
    array
  'id_product' => string '9' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Brady ENV100 MAXX Enhanced Sorbents' (length=35)
  'number_sold' => string '6' (length=1)
  'link_rewrite' => string 'brady-env100-maxx-enhanced-sorbents' (length=35)
  'id_image' => string '27' (length=2)
 1 => 
array
  'id_product' => string '10' (length=2)
  'name' => string 'Brady GP100 MAXX Enhanced Heavy Pad' (length=35)
  'number_sold' => string '3' (length=1)
  'link_rewrite' => string 'brady-gp100-maxx-enhanced-heavy-pad' (length=35)
  'id_image' => string '29' (length=2)

array
 0 => 
array
  'id_product' => string '9' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Height' (length=6)
  'value' => string '5' (length=1)
 1 => 
array
  'id_product' => string '9' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Width' (length=5)
  'value' => string '5' (length=1)
 2 => 
array
  'id_product' => string '9' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Depth' (length=5)
  'value' => string '5' (length=1)
  3 => 
array
  'id_product' => string '9' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Weight' (length=6)
  'value' => string '5' (length=1)
 4 => 
array
  'id_product' => string '10' (length=2)
  'name' => string 'Height' (length=6)
  'value' => string '10' (length=2)
```

I have looked at many tutorials, but can't seem to get anything to work. What I would like it to look like is

```
array
0 => 
array
'id_product' => string '9' (length=1)
'name' => string 'Brady ENV100 MAXX Enhanced Sorbents' (length=35)
'number_sold' => string '6' (length=1)
'link_rewrite' => string 'brady-env100-maxx-enhanced-sorbents' (length=35)
'id_image' => string '27' (length=2)
name' => string 'Height' (length=6)
'value' => string '5' (length=1)
 'name' => string 'Width' (length=5)
'value' => string '5' (length=1)
'name' => string 'Depth' (length=5)
'value' => string '5' (length=1)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

For your product array do this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($mainItems as $item){
    $result[$item["id_product"]] = $item;
}
```

Then for each of your attribute arrays

```
foreach($attributes as $val){
    if (array_key_exists($val["id_product"], $result)){
        $result[$val["id_product"]][$val["name"]] = $val["value"];
    }
}
```

You should end up with an array that looks like

```
[9] => array(
       [id_product] => 9
       [name] => "Brady ENV100 MAXX Enhanced Sorbents"
       [number_sold] => "6"
       [link_rewrite] => "brady-env100-maxx-enhanced-sorbents"
       [id_image] => "27"
       [Height] => 5
       [Width] => 5
       [Depth] => 5  
),
[10] => array(
       [id_product] =>  '10' 
       [name] =>  'Brady GP100 MAXX Enhanced Heavy Pad' 
       [number_sold] => '3'
       [link_rewrite] =>  'brady-gp100-maxx-enhanced-heavy-pad' 
       [id_image] =>  '29'
```

Comment: I tried the following code                                         $results = array();
  foreach ($data as $item) {
   $results[$item["id_product"]] = $item;
  }
  
  foreach($features as $val) {
   if (array_key_exists($results[$val["id_product"]])){
    $results[$val["id_product"]][$val["name"]] = $val["value"];
   }
  }
  
  var_dump($results);   but I get an error that says  array_key_exists() expects exactly 2 parameters